# Why do "force create mode" and "force directory mode" parameters exist in smb.conf?

Tags: networking, files, filesystems, directory, samba

I am reading [How to Set Up a Network Shared Folder on Ubuntu With Samba](https://www.makeuseof.com/set-up-network-shared-folder-ubuntu-with-samba/). At the "Step 2: Configuring Samba" section the following configuration is given:

```bash
[sambashare]
comment= Network Shared Folder by Samba Server on Ubuntu
path = /home/your_username/sambashare
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
read only = no
```

Observe the relation about:

- `create mask` with `force create mode`
- `directory mask` with `force directory mode`

These two pairs of parameters have the same value.

Why aren't the `create mask` and `directory mask` parameters enough by themselves? Why do the `force create mode` and `force directory mode` parameters exist?

I've read in the official documentation of [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) the [smb.conf(5)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) page, where it has the "Explanation Of Each Parameter" section. But for these two "force" parameters, the reason of their existence is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the linked documentation says:

> #### create mode
>
> This parameter is a synonym for [create mask](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMASK).
>
> #### create mask (S)
>
> When a file is created, the necessary permissions are calculated
> according to the mapping from DOS modes to UNIX permissions, and the
> resulting UNIX mode is then bit-wise 'AND'ed with this parameter. This
> parameter may be thought of as a bit-wise MASK for the UNIX modes of a
> file. Any bit not set here will be removed from the modes set on a
> file when it is created. [...]
>
> Following this Samba will bit-wise 'OR' the UNIX mode created from
> this parameter with the value of the [force create mode](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#FORCECREATEMODE) parameter which
> is set to 000 by default.

So:

- `create mask` removes disallowed (masked) permissions from the provided permission for the file to be created
- `force create mode` adds required permissions to the file to be created

For example, let's say you want:

1. Files to not have group-write permissions and no permissions for others
2. Files to always have owner-write permissions (but you don't care if other permissions are present or not for owner)

Then:

1. For (1), `create mask` will be `750`:

   - You don't care what the user adds for the owner permissions, so `7` to allow everything.
   - You don't want group write permissions, so only read and execute are allowed, hence `5` for group.
   - `0` for others to disallow everything.
2. For (2), `force create mask` will be `200`

   - You absolutely want write to be present, so `2` for owner, and then `0` for the rest because those are irrelevant.

So if a user tries to create a file with permissions `475` (read for owner, everything for group and read-execute for others), this will then result in `(475 & 750) | 200` = `450 | 200` = `650` (read *and* write for owner, read-execute for group). The write permission for group and permissions for others were removed by `create mask`, and write permission for owner was added by `force create mode`.